# Counting Combinations With SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, dataframe, impala

I have a data table with a unique transaction_id and many columns of 0/1 value variables. I'm trying to figure out how to count and summarise each combination and display the output - my data table is in a impala database and I'm trying to use sql to solve the problem.

For example:

```
0001 / 1 / 0 / 1 / 0

0002 / 0 / 1 / 1 / 1

0003 / 1 / 0 / 1 / 0
```

I want an output that reads:

```
Combo A (1/0/1/0) = 2

Combo B (0/1/1/1) = 1
```

Is there an efficient way of achieving this as I am dealing with 100,000's rows of data.

Thanks,

Comment: and why would it be 1 and not 3?

Comment: Because the combination of 0/1/1/1 has only appeared once in the table while 1/0/1/0 has appeared twice. I'm not trying to sum the columns together. Trying to count distinct combinations across all transaction.

Comment: i see. can you please post the contents of your table.

Comment: It is on my work computer, but it is very similar to the example I have posted just with about 15 variables.

Comment: I would amend the schema

Comment: Some variation of select count ... group by. Try that and post a question if necessary. As it stands this is too generic for the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking to your data sample

You can use a proper conbiation of count and group by

```
select   count(*), col1, col2, col3, col4
from your table  
group by col1, col2, col3, col4
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.